# Laravel eloquent relationships error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationships

Basically, I'm trying to create a relation between user, post and reply db's. Here are the models: 
comment model

```
<?php

namespace App\Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class comments extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $table = 'comments';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function userInfo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Eloquent\User', 'user_id');
    }
    public function reply()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Eloquent\reply', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

reply mode:

```
<?php

namespace App\Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class reply extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $table = 'replies';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];


    function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Eloquent\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

main code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Eloquent\comments;
use App\Eloquent\reply;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $commentsData = [];
        $replyData = [];
            $comments = comments::all();
        foreach ($comments as $comment)
        {
            if($comments !== null) {
                $user = comments::find($comment->user_id)->userInfo();
                $reply = comments::find($comment->id)->reply();
            }
            if(reply::all() !== null) {
                $user_reply = reply::find($comment->id)->user();
            }
            $commentsData[$comment->id]['name'] = $user->name;
            $commentsData[$comment->id]['message'] = $comment->body;
            $commentsData[$comment->id]['rating'] = $comment->rating;
            $commentsData[$comment->id]['timestamp'] = $comment->created_at;
            foreach($reply as $re)
            {
                $replyData[$re->post_id][$re->id]['name'] = $user_reply->name;
                $replyData[$re->post_id][$re->id]['body'] = $reply->body;
            }

        }

        return view('comments')->with('comments', $commentsData)->with('reply', $replyData);
    }
}
```

When I'm accesing the comments page, I'm getting the following error:

> Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name.

It's my first time using relationships, so I checked the Laravel docs, but still have no idea what I did wrong. Basically what I'm trying to get is to get user's name from users database (using comments user_id as foreign), get comment details (body, rating) and get the reply data, using post_id (in reply table) as foreign and comments table primary key ID as local key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting relation definition from your models instead of the related objects.

Replace

```
$user = comments::find($comment->user_id)->userInfo();
$reply = comments::find($comment->id)->reply();
$user_reply = reply::find($comment->id)->user();
```

with

```
$user = comments::find($comment->user_id)->userInfo;
$reply = comments::find($comment->id)->reply;
$user_reply = reply::find($comment->id)->user;
```

Note the removed brackets at the very end of those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes regarding some relations in your foreach loop which will make it faster and more usable

> You are using relationship and still finding user using array key it's more likely to use on **$comment** bcz $comment is already Model and you can apply relationship on that easily. as same as for replay Model.

```
foreach ($comments as $comment)
    {
        $user = $comment->userInfo();
        $reply = $comment->reply();

        $commentsData[$comment->id]['name'] = $user->name;
        $commentsData[$comment->id]['message'] = $comment->body;
        $commentsData[$comment->id]['rating'] = $comment->rating;
        $commentsData[$comment->id]['timestamp'] = $comment->created_at;
          foreach($reply as $re)
            {
                $replyData[$re->post_id][$re->id]['name'] = $re->user()->name;
                $replyData[$re->post_id][$re->id]['body'] = $re->body;
            }
        }
```